# Docker - COPY fails when app has not been built locally?

Tags: docker, gradle, jar, dockerfile, build.gradle

I have the following `dockerfile` :

```
# Prepare runtime.
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

# Prepare build workspace.
FROM gradle:5.3.0-jdk-alpine AS sdk
WORKDIR /build-workspace

# Accept build args.
ARG ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_mavenUser
ARG ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_mavenPassword

# Setup build workspace.
USER root
RUN chown -R gradle .
USER gradle

# Copy.
COPY build.gradle .
COPY gradle.properties .
COPY src ./src

# Build, Test and publish.
RUN gradle clean build bootJar

# App image.
FROM runtime
COPY /build/libs/myApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ./app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

The app is a `spring boot` MVC web application, and the `dockerfile` is in the root dir beside `build.gradle` etc

When I run:

```
docker build -t myApp .
```

I get:

```
Step 16/17 : COPY /build/libs/myApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ./app.jar
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder441781405/build/libs/myApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar: no such file or directory
```

When I build the app locally first with gradle the dockerfile works - assumably as it can see the build folder.

How can I alter my dockerfile so that the local build is not needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `COPY --from=sdk /build-workspace/libs/myApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ./app.jar`

with `--from=sdk` your are telling Docker to copy the file from the gradle build stage without it docker will copy it from your local filesystem.

for more Information [see](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)